# Inserir jquery cycle 2 no wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```js
<!--cycle6-->

<?php
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle.all.js', '/wp-content/themes/powerclub-lite/js/jquery.cycle2.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle2.flip.js', '/wp-content/themes/powerclub-lite/js/jquery.cycle2.flip.js');
   wp_head();
   wp_enqueue_script('cycle6', '/wp-content/themes/powerclub-lite/js/cycle6.js');
   wp_head();
?>
```

```css
.galeria1 {width: 50%}
.galeria1  img {width: 100%; Altura: auto}
```

```html
<!-- inicio jq cycle body -->
<div style="" id="galeria1"> <img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 5; opacity: 1;" src="http://localhost/academia/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/home_historia_1-min-1.png" alt="Primeira Foto" /><img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 4; opacity: 1;" src="http://localhost/academia/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/home_matematica_3-min-1.png" alt="Primeira Foto" /></div>

<!-- fim jq cycle body →
```

consegui inserir o jquery cycle 1 no wordpress normalmente, mas com o cycle2, estou tentando a dias, ja procurei muito e nada, por isso estou pedindo ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Em um primeiro momento, insira na forma de **HTML** para ver o que está ocorrendo de errado. Faça isso no **header.php** do seu template. Veja:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="/wp-content/themes/powerclub-lite/js/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>

<script src="/wp-content/themes/powerclub-lite/js/jquery.cycle2.flip.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado, não aconteceu nada, nem deu erro e não funcionou o efeito. jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#galeria1').cycle('flipHorz');
}); o efeito trava, se colocar o efeito do cycle1 funciona, tipo zoom, este efeito desejo usar:<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=flipHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=2000
    >
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Consegui da seguinte forma:

```js
<!--no header.php do tema-->

<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.flip.js"></script>
```

```html
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=flipHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=2000
    >
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg"/>
</div>
```